# Allow selection of which activity to use as default

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities named `One_Activity` and `two_activity`.

After allowing the user to make a selection I want to allow the app to decide which activity to display - even if we exit from the program and return.

For instance we should always launch `two_activity` as the default if we selected it.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend on JoelFernandes suggestion, which is a correct solution, your launch activity will need to check `SharedPreferences` as follows

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int MODE_LAUNCH_A = 0;
    public static final int MODE_LAUNCH_B = 1;
    public static final String PREF_LAUNCH_MODE = "PREF_LAUNCH_MODE";

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Intent target;
        switch(prefs.getInteger(PREF_LAUNCH_MODE, 0)) {
             case MODE_LAUNCH_A:
                 target = new Intent(this, AlphaActivity,class);
                 break;
             case MODE_LAUNCH_B:
                 target = new Intent(this, BravoActivity,class);
                 break;
        }
        startActivity(target);
    }

}
```

In the Activity where you select the Activity to use as the Main Activity you need to save the preference like follows:

```
private void saveSelection(int selection) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    prefs.edit().setInteger(MainActivity.PREF_LAUNCH_MODE, selection).commit; //(or .apply() instead of commit)
}

// call the above method like
saveSelection(MainActivity.MODE_LAUNCH_A);
```

In the manifest you should also set NoHistory on MainActivity to stop it making a mess when you press the back button.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag and save it in `SharedPreferences`. When you reopen the app, access the flag and depending on its value, you can show the desired activity as your main activity.